# Improving AI model for categorical outcome predictions

Tags: python, beginner, machine-learning, ai

I am a novice and would appreciate some guidance. I have been trying to create a machine learning code that will correlatate 10+ binary variable and maybe a couple continuous variables to a binary ( or ideal trinary) categorization. Using python

So far I am using sci kit learn and have a training set in the format of :

```
X_train = [[a1,b1,c1,…n1], [a2,b2,c2,…n2],…] ## where a,b,c etc are yes(1)/no(2) ##
Y_train= [[category1 (yes/no/possible)], [category2 (yes/no/possible)],…]
```

Then it finds coefficients

```
Xa1 + Yb1 + Zc1 = category1
Xa2 + Yb2 + Zc2 = category2
…
…
…
```

Prints coefficients

Then takes user input data or a test data set and outputs predictions of which category based on original input combinations.

My question is : is there a better way to do this/ modify this so it is more suitable for yes / no inputs as well as yes/ no output? Because the output categories are not necessarily ordinal (they could ultimately be), but I don’t know, so using 1 and 2 could more/ less accurate than be 1 and 3 or 3 and 1 etc.

See below :

```
from random import randint



TRAIN_INPUT = [[2,0,2,2], [2,2,2,2], [2,1,2,2], [1,2,1,1], [2,1,1,2], [1,2,2,2], 
[2,1,2,2],
[1,1,2,2], [2,1,2,2], [1,2,2,2]]

TRAIN_OUTPUT = [[5],[5],[5],[5],[5],[4],[4],[4],[4],[4]]

print(TRAIN_INPUT)
print(TRAIN_OUTPUT)


from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

predictor = LinearRegression(n_jobs=-1)
predictor.fit(X=TRAIN_INPUT, y=TRAIN_OUTPUT)


X_TEST = [[1, 2, 2, 2]]
outcome = predictor.predict(X=X_TEST)
coefficients = predictor.coef_

print('Outcome : {}\nCoefficients : {}'.format(outcome, coefficients))
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Given the statement "_I am a novice_" you could [edit] and add the [tag:beginner] tag if desired.

Comment: If your output variable is categorical by nature, you can simply try `LogisticRegression` instead of `LinearRegression`. And for input variables you can try to use `OneHotEncoder`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help!! As I said I’m a greenhorn….Would you be able to elaborate a bit on where I can use those? My output variable is indeed categorical.  Kindly,